# Cannot locate class span element with Selenium + Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Trying to Automate the test case.
Please anyone explain me how can I locate span class element?
Or even more, how to locate an element within an element and afterwards select from the drop down list? Few hours of work are in vain...

This is the class I am trying to locate:

```
<span class="labelText___1_7Q2">Erstzulassung ab</span>
```

This is the structure of the task I am trying to execute:

[image: drop down menu]

[HTML source code](https://pasteboard.co/I63oi59.jpg)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the above span by using the xpath:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Erstzulassung ab']"));
```

And you can also parameterise the xpath if you want to use the same xpath to select different `elements` with different values like:

```
String text = null;
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()="+text+"]"));
```

And then you can just send the expected value in the `text` string here or you can just directly set the xpath like the first one i have used.

Comment: You should replace `null` with `'Erstzulassung ab'` for a more clear example. Setting `text` to `null` and then using it is going to throw an exception.